# align text "boxes" vertically

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I have attached a current screenshot of my webpage for more clarity. I would like to move the "data structs and algorithms" text circle directly below the purple text circle. I am assuming that the reason for the white space below the purple text circle is because of the large dark blue one on the top left, however I can't seem to figure out how to override that. Currently, the text "boxes" all have the display: inline-block property so that they will be displayed side by side. I attempted to search for a similar question but did not find any with this specific problem.
[image: screenshot of webpage]

Comment: You need something like http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: you can position the elements with position: absolute

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted any code so there is not way to see how you are composing your elements, however the flexible box model or `display: flex;` seems like it should be of use to you.

As you can see in this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c4q1f6sz/1/):

```
display: flex;
```

and

```
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

Cause your divs to fill the empty space even if they are of varying size.

Comment: I think this is on the right track, however, now my divs are now all lined up right above each other, pushed all the way to the left of the screen. How do I have this feature to fill not only vertical space but also horizontal space? I would like them to remain side by side

Comment: [This resouce explains the features of flexboxes pretty well](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) Take a look at `justify-content` and `flex-direction`.